# Статический класс вместо глобальных переменных?

Tags: php, ооп

Изучаю ООП путем создания простой CMS. Для функционирования CMS в различных её частях необходим доступ к настройкам из объекта Config (главный URL, пути и др), объекту Routing, объекту Template (запись переменных для отображения в шаблоне) и др. Какие существуют способы обеспечить доступ к таким объектам в любой части скрипта?

На сколько я понял для этого можно использовать Singleton или статический класс. Для себя выбрал статический класс, так как для его вызова (получения нужного объекта) нужно на одну строчку кода меньше, а суть, в сравнении с Синглтоном одинакова.

```
class Storage
{
    private static $routing = null;

    public static function setRouting(object $routing)
    {
        if (null === self::$routing) {
            self::$routing = $routing;
        }
    }

    public static function getRouting()
    {
        return self::$routing;
    }
}
```

Класс инициализируется при старте скрипта:

```
use Storage;

Storage::setRouting($routing);
```

Насколько оправдано такое решение?

Answer (score 1):

Моё мнение: если сравнивать статический класс или одиночку, то лучше одиночка. Статика создаёт жёсткие связи по всему проекту. В то время как одиночку можно, в принципе даже, применить в паре с инъекцией зависимостей (ему ничего не мешает реализовывать интерфейсы, его можно пробросить через конструктор).

Пример одиночки:

```
<?php 

class Storage
{
   private static $instanse = null;

   public static function getInstance() 
   {
       if (null === self::$instance) {
           self::$instance = new Singleton();
       }

       return self::$instance;
   }

   private $routing = null;

   private function __construct() { }
   private function __clone() { }

   public function setRouting($value)
   {
       $this->routing = $value;
       return $this;
   }

   public function getRouting()
   {
       return $this->routing;
   }
}
```

Пример вызова:

```
Storage::getInstance()->setRouting($routing);
```